# Fix all import paths in project after dir structure refactoring in PyCharm

Tags: import, pycharm, refactoring

Does anybody know how to automatically fix all wrong import paths after moving folders inside the PyCharm python project?

Comment: The right approach would have been right-clicking in Project View on the folders you wanted to move and choosing `Refactor` `>` `Move directory` (or F6). That way PyCharm would have reorganized all the imports for you when moving the dir/module. Maybe [optimize imports](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-and-optimizing-imports.html#46e6ef43) can fix this but probably not everything.

Comment: I even use Refactor->move directory but became broken import links.

Comment: I have upgraded PyCharm to 2020.3 and run optimize imports, but it doesn't help

Comment: These documentation pages [one](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/move-refactorings.html) and [two](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/refactoring-source-code.html#refactoring_invoke) are pretty good. If it isn't working for the whole directory try with an individual module first, then with several modules. It as worked for me (and documentation says it should) although there have been times when it did break some references it tends to work more than it fails.

Comment: OK, try ["Move a file or a directory to another directory"](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/move-refactorings.html#move-file-directory) and there's a checkbox called "Search for references" in that dialogue. Try ticking that checkbox.

Comment: I've given this some more thought, for example if you are using [development install](https://docs.python.org/3/installing/index.html) the problem with refactoring a directory is that PyCharm is looking at your source files by first looking at the egg file. So if you start refactoring entire packages (directories) you have to uninstall and install again. But this can be a sort of *"catch 22"* situation because after you uninstall the fully qualified names your imports use might not be reflected by the source files (because the file/directory structure is different from the installed version.)